# Convert Multiple XML files and XSLT files to One PDF using c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, pdf

How can i Convert Multiple XML files and XSLT files to One PDF using c# ?

Comment: I think you have to elaborate a little further...

Comment: try this http://www.convertapi.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDF creation process is very simple. irrespective of file types the files can be read and written to a pdf object. For that you need a custom pdf conversion tools. Add the dll tool to the project, refer it and convert your files.

Apart for that I would like to know "What have you done and is there any additional requirement on the same?" Do you want to convert open XML and XSLT document and then write to pdf.